# Category product menu bar not linking

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made a category menu bar on my website so you can click on a category and see products of that category, but its not working for me and I must be doing something wrong.

```
Some database information:

categories table:
Row 1: id
Row 2: name

In the products table:
Row: category_id
```

I used a db helper (db_helper.php)

```
<?php if (!function_exists('get_categories_h')) {
    function get_categories_h(){
        $CI = get_instance();
        $categories = $CI->Product_model->get_categories();
        return $categories;
    } } ?>
```

This is the my Product_model file where I made the get_categories function:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_model extends CI_model {

    public function saveProduct($data) { 
        $this->db->insert('products', $data);
        $product_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $product_id;
    }
    public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }
    /*
      Get categories
     */
    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('categories'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

And this is the menu bar in my view file where I'm loading all my categories.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="<?php echo $category->id; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?>
                                </a> 
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am able to echo all the categories from my database but the links are not working. 
I hope someone can help me,
Thanks!

Comment: <a href="<?<?php echo $category->id; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?>
                                </a> here is two php opening tag

Comment: `<?<?php` TYPO I think. You should start all debugging by first looking at your PHP ERROR LOG

Comment: Hey I tried that and its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $category->id;?>"> 
        <?php echo $category['name']; ?>
    </a> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating a nonsense URL for the href value. Unless the 'id' field of the 'categories' table contains values that use a "controller/method/id" scheme the links you are creating don't go anywhere.

The 'id' field probably just contains numbers. Yes?

If so, your links probably look something like `http://example.com/123` which isn't going to go anywhere unless you have a controller named "123".

You need hrefs that go somewhere. I recommend using the `anchor()` function of Codeigniter [URL Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor). You will need to load that helper before this example will work.

```
<?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <?php echo anchor("controller_name/controller_method/{$category->id}", $category['name']); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Without the `anchor()` function it would be written

```
<a href="controller_name/controller_method/<?php echo $category->id;?>"> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
```

Comment: I dont have any controller functions for my category products function so where do i need to link it, im only using a helper model and a view to echo the categories from my database

Comment: Your question states "the links are not working". My answer explains why. What do you expect the links to do?